# Error: Cannot resolve module 'apply' webpack angular2

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, angular, webpack

I am not really sure how I got into this pickle.. I uninstalled my global webpack and reinstalled it locally to dockerize my project. Then I got a trail of errors, resolved the ones I could and I'm left with this

http://puu.sh/orazd/b8a85ac5c6.png

I don't use any module called `apply`, most certainly not in every file

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be

[image]

silly enough.. the error was a little misleading but.

Answer (score 3):

I had tried **[resolveLoader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolveloader)** previously

and it had worked for me.

My configuration is as follows:

```
resolveLoader: {
  modulesDirectories: [
      '/users/path/a/node_modules'
  ]
},
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Though not sure, I think maybe something wrong, like conflicts, in the `typings` folder. Would you try to remove `typings` folder and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just produces type errors alongside the original error. You should use comments instead of answers for things you aren't sure about it for the benefit of other readers, and so that others will still attempt to answer my question. But thanks just the same :)